# Springboot 2.4.0-RC1 and Spring Cloud Config (Illford) - java.lang.VerifyError: Cannot inherit from final class

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config, spring-cloud-config-server

We bumped our stack to spring boot 2.4.0-RC1 and spring cloud 2020.0.0-M4 Illford.

On a very simple:

```
@EnableConfigServer
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class);
    }

}
```

```
 <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0-RC1</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>2020.0.0-M4</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

It is failing with java.lang.VerifyError: Cannot inherit from final class  at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)

Complete stack trace:

```
04:21:28.708 [main] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
java.lang.VerifyError: Cannot inherit from final class
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:698)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:621)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:579)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398)
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeNamedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:114)
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:125)
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49)
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.reifyTypeArguments(Reifier.java:68)
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:138)
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49)
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.repository.ClassRepository.computeSuperInterfaces(ClassRepository.java:117)
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.repository.ClassRepository.getSuperInterfaces(ClassRepository.java:95)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getGenericInterfaces(Class.java:1137)
    at org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.getInterfaces(ResolvableType.java:502)
    at org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.as(ResolvableType.java:450)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataLoaders.getResourceType(ConfigDataLoaders.java:88)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataLoaders.getResourceTypes(ConfigDataLoaders.java:82)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataLoaders.<init>(ConfigDataLoaders.java:76)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataLoaders.<init>(ConfigDataLoaders.java:56)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironment.<init>(ConfigDataEnvironment.java:146)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor.getConfigDataEnvironment(ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor.postProcessEnvironment(ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor.java:88)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor.postProcessEnvironment(ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor.java:80)
    at org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.java:100)
    at org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.java:86)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:203)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:196)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:170)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:148)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:82)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.lambda$environmentPrepared$2(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:63)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:117)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:111)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:62)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:362)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1309)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1298)
    at twofour.Application.main(Application.java:12)
```

Tried the new boot strap properties, bootstrap rules and spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap, all without success.

What is the solution please?

Thank you

Comment: Which final class is something try to extend?

Comment: Hello @AndyWilkinson, no extends at all, it is out of the box error

Comment: Something, not necessarily in your code, must be trying to extend a final class, otherwise the error that you are seeing wouldn't not be occurring. Which class it is that's doing that should be apparent from the exception. Could you update the question to include the complete stack trace?

Comment: Of course, updated

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately that hasn't helped as neither the stack trace not the exception message's reveal any information about which class is illegally trying to extend a `final` class. You may be able to find out which class is causing the problem by setting an exception breakpoint for `java.lang.VerifyError` and then looking at the name of the class that was being defined.

Comment: no problem, many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problem. Same versions, but I'm using Kotlin instead of Java.

I think the problem could be that Spring Cloud 2020.0.0-M4 it isn't yet compatible with Spring Boot 2.4.0-RC1.

The class `org.springframework.cloud.config.client.ConfigServerConfigDataLocation` tries to extend the final class `org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataLocation`

Comment: Do you know a compatible combination between SpringBoot 2.4.x and Illford please?

Comment: @PatPatPat This combination works: Spring Boot 2.4.0-M3 and Spring Cloud 2020.0.0-M4